# Git don't track files only upload

Tags: php, git

I want to have files in my repo but don't want to track the changes in the clones is there a way to do that without setting files to assume-unchanged through a deploy script?

Example:

Server bare.git holds a file custom.php
Local repo pulls bare.git gets the custom.php but don't track changes to the file

I read about config files but I don't want to make the files with a deploy script I want the file to be in the repo and gets cloned but not to be tracked by the cloned repo.

Comment: Using assume-unchanged is a mistaken understanding of the documentation. '--assume-unchanged' is a promise by you that you won't change the file (on slow file systems). Git will still check for changes with some commands giving you a surprise. The documentation is being updated. Look at `--skip-worktree`. Git isn't a deployment tool.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way of doing this, and there probably a problem with your workflow if you need this. If `config.php` needs to be changed on each instance (for example, to add credentials specific to that environment), you probably want the following accepted pattern:

- Rename that file to `config.php.example`
- Add `config.php` to `.gitignore`
- In each clone, copy `config.php.example` to `config.php` and make the necessary local changes

Otherwise, the entire purpose of Git is to track change to files. If you don't want changes to a file tracked, don't track it.

Comment: ok in case its one file thats a good way but in my case its a folder thats about 2000 Files.
Background i want to integrate a module from a other developer in my repo this module gets updates to the files through php scripts.

Comment: Again, your workflow is incorrect. You shouldn't have 2000 files inside your Git repo if you don't want to track changes to those files. Those 2000 files should be in their own repository, so that change to them *can* be tracked, and they should be included in your other repositories through whatever means of code-reuse/distribution your language supports. The worst-case scenario would be including them with a submodule. Git isn't for solving this problem.

Comment: ok thanks for your reply i think i have to overthink my workflow. maybe putting the files in a directory outside the docroot and pulling them throug my deploy script once if the don't exist in the docroot of the repo where they gets .gitignored